# Generate a jar file with all the source files in a multi-module project in SBT

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I have a multi-module project with the following structure:

```
lazy val main = project.in(file(".")).
                aggregate(moduleA,moduleB,...).
                dependsOn(moduleA, moduleB,...).
                ...

lazy val moduleA = project.in(file("modules/moduleA")).
                   ...
lazy val moduleB = project.in(file("modules/moduleB")).
                   ...
```

I want to generate a jar containing the source code of the root module and the source code of the rest of the modules. How can I do it?

I was able to generate a binary jar with all the class files using the universal task from `sbt-native-packager`.